# When using pandas_profiling: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visions.application'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vision, pandas-profiling

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Whilst importing pandas profile (please see above command), I am getting the following error message:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3396/1468051405.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py in <module>
      5 
      6 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, config
----> 7 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
      8 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      9 from pandas_profiling.version import __version__

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\controller\pandas_decorator.py in <module>
      2 from pandas import DataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from pandas_profiling.__init__ import ProfileReport
      5 
      6 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, config
      7 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
----> 8 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      9 from pandas_profiling.version import __version__
     10 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from pandas_profiling.config import config
---> 11 from pandas_profiling.model.describe import describe as describe_df
     12 from pandas_profiling.model.messages import MessageType
     13 from pandas_profiling.report import get_report_structure

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\describe.py in <module>
      9 from pandas_profiling.model.base import Variable
     10 from pandas_profiling.model.correlations import calculate_correlation
---> 11 from pandas_profiling.model.summary import (
     12     get_duplicates,
     13     get_messages,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\summary.py in <module>
     11 import pandas as pd
     12 from scipy.stats.stats import chisquare
---> 13 from visions.application.summaries.series import (
     14     file_summary,
     15     image_summary,

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visions.application'
```

I have made sure that the vision module version is 0.7.4 as 0.7.5 is not compatible with pandas-profiling.

**Does anyone have an idea about how you resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the 'visions.application' module was available in v0.7.1

https://github.com/dylan-profiler/visions/tree/v0.7.1/src/visions

But it's no longer available in v0.7.2

https://github.com/dylan-profiler/visions/tree/v0.7.2/src/visions

It also appears that the [pandas_profiling](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling) project has been updated, the file summary.py no longer tries to do this import.

In summary: use visions version v0.7.1 or upgrade pandas_profiling.